# Destroying table created with Flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

Is there any way to dynamically destroy a table I created with Flexigrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove it the same way you'd remove any other DOM element.  So if you had:

```
$('#flexi').flexigrid();
```

Then you would just do:

```
$('#flexi').remove();
```